# PostgreSQL array in form type: value

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Is there any way to create an array in PostgreSQL which contains multiple data types in form ***type:value***?

For example, one of the table records should be an array with values ***height:190, color:black*** etc. 
If it isn't possible with arrays, how could I mannage this other way?

Comment: you are probably looking for hstore or json

Comment: you can use json as column type. You read about the same on postgres official page.

Comment: *"how could I manage this other way?"* -- Captain Obvious here ... By using multiple columns, and possibly an associated table. (If you don't want to go the JSON route, that is.)

Comment: This data structure called [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) BTW.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html

> This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of
>   key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value

```
t=# select ('height=>190, color=>black')::hstore;
              hstore
-----------------------------------
 "color"=>"black", "height"=>"190"
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html

> JSON data types are for storing JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)
>   data, as specified in RFC 7159. Such data can also be stored as text,
>   but the JSON data types have the advantage of enforcing that each
>   stored value is valid according to the JSON rules.

```
t=# select '{"height":190, "color":"black"}'::json;
              json
---------------------------------
 {"height":190, "color":"black"}
(1 row)
```